# Get reference to LinearLayout in fragment

Tags: android, fragment

In the XML file for my layout I added a fragment.
The layout for my fragment is a LinearLayout and it contains a text view.

I want to get a reference to the LinearLayout object in my fragment class, but despite trying everything I can think of or find online, it is always null.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    text = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text);
    layout = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.layout);

    if(layout == null){
        text.setText("null");
    }
}
```

This code is in my fragment class and results in the TextView's text being set to "null" since the layout is null. How could this be since I am trying to get the references to the layout and the textview in the exact same way?

---

onCreate in activity class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    manager = getFragmentManager();
    MyFragment = (MyFragment) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);

}
```

---

Method 2

I tried getting a reference to the LinearLayout in my activity. Here is the activity's onCreate with this attempt.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    manager = getFragmentManager();
    MyFragment = (MyFragment) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    if(ll == null){
        tv.setText("null");
    }
}
```

This also changed the text to "null."

Comment: Post your  `Activity.onCreate` please. If the views are being created in your activity I recommend you to move the code to your activity

Comment: You're trying to get the `LinearLayout` of the `Fragment` from your `Activity`? Am I getting it right?

Comment: Are you referencing the `getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text)`? I have also tried `getView().findViewById(...)` in the `onActivityCreated()` to just go through the fragment, but that didn't work either

Answer (score 1):

The problem is fixed in both cases by saying `layout = (LinearLayout) getView()` in the fragment class or `layout = (LinearLayout) fragment.getView()` in the activity. This doesn't answer why what I was doing didn't work (which could be helpful) but this solves the problem.